# How to fix Your Ruby version is 2.7.4, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.3

Tags: react-native, macos, rubygems, gemspecs

While I’m creating an react native new project in Mac OS . Im getting an error like “***Your Ruby version is 2.7.4, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.3”***

How to solve this ?

Comment: Change the version in Gemfile with the installed version

Comment: @MrinalMaheshwari how to change to gemfile installed version ? In Mac OS

Comment: Install `rbenv`, use this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-macos) and you can install any version of ruby you want

Comment: @MrinalMaheshwari still I’m getting same issue. Any solution ???

Comment: I had the same issue and this post helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71371079/fix-your-ruby-version-is-2-6-8-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-5-5

Comment: you can follow the guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38194231/20098426). should fix your problem easily

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing the version in the file `.ruby-version` that lives in the root of the app folder.

Answer (score 0):

Install rvm which stands for ruby version manager
Visit https://rvm.io/rvm/install or follow the instructions

1.

> gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys
> 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
> 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB

If gpg is not installed, install it using brew install gnupg.

2.

> \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby

3. Change and install ruby using rvm,

   rvm install 2.7.3
   rvm use 2.7.3

use rvm list to show all ruby version installed

Answer (score -1):

Please follow this simple steps :
https://nrogap.medium.com/install-rvm-in-macos-step-by-step-d3b3c236953b

Answer (score -1):

Goto the project root directory. You will find a file called **.ruby-version** and open it. Edit it and change 2.7.3 to 2.7.4 and save.