# How do I fix "Your Ruby version is 3.1.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.5" when installing React-Native?

Tags: javascript, ruby, react-native, macos

How do I fix this error?

error Your Ruby version is 3.1.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.5

✖ Installing Bundler
error Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.

I am using macOS and home-brew as well.

I've tried changing ruby version to 2.7.5 using rbenv. However, when I type rbenv global 2.7.5 or rbenv local 2.7.5, it won't change the version.

Comment: checkout this page [problem with ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71371079/fix-your-ruby-version-is-2-6-8-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-5-5)

Answer (score 1):

The command you’re looking for is `rbenv shell 2.7.5`. This will change your shell environment to run in the necessary Ruby version.